# Exception on getting data in SQL Server from my web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have created a new table in my SQL Server database. When I want to take data from newly created table then my application throws an exception. I've debugged the code and found that it can not get data from the new table. Spelling is correct , object is correct and all the things are perfectly working, but when calling data from these tables my application bursts.

I used `"SELECT * FROM GROUPS"` working fine with the old table. The name of the new table is `APPLICATION` in same db with 4 rows.

I used `"SELECT * FROM APPLICATION"` and it throws an exception. while it does have data. Here is my code for GROUPS which is working:

```
public DataTable getAllRO()
{
  const string query_ = "SELECT * FROM GROUPS ";
  SHMA.Enterprise.Data.ParameterCollection pc = new SHMA.Enterprise.Data.ParameterCollection();
  return DAL.executeQuery_DT(query_, pc);
}
```

And for calling this:

```
 GROUPSDB objGroup = new GROUPSDB(dataHolder);
 listerData = objGroup.getAllRO();
```

But same code for table `APPLICATION` is not working.

Comment: You have taged C# and ASP.NET. If this is related to one of these tags(i assume C#) then show us also some code. How have you tried to execute the query and what's the full exception, where did it occur?

Comment: oledb object not found........ i have checked it its mean is data is not recieving

Comment: protected override void GetListerData()
        {
            GROUPSDB objGroup = new GROUPSDB(dataHolder);
            listerData = objGroup.getAllRO();
        }

Comment: You are targetting the wrong database, test the query in sql mgmt studio and ensure it works here. Also post your connection string.

Comment: public DataTable getAllRO()
    {
        const string query_ = "SELECT * FROM GROUPS ";
        SHMA.Enterprise.Data.ParameterCollection pc = new SHMA.Enterprise.Data.ParameterCollection();
        return DAL.executeQuery_DT(query_, pc);
    }

Comment: above code is working fine ........ but same code for table APPLICATION and same method for table application is not working

Comment: @mak: Don't post code in the comments but in your question(with proper formatting). Have you tried to use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`?

Comment: ok im editing my question\

Comment: i have my own library .... but work is simple calling  . i think db is not updating

Comment: @faester querry works fine

Comment: Computers are stupid, is everything is the same, it **will** work the same. Try getting another pair of eyes to look at the code, as you walk through it.

Comment: querry is running in sql does not need brackets umesh

Comment: @SWeko why all the all old tables with the above code is working ? and after making new table when i put only table name it throws exeption. i think sql is not updated after making new tables , or problem som thing like update.

Comment: That is my point exactly, something is different, explain everything to another developer or to a [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and the problem should present itself.